# RestKit Custom Response Mapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit-0.20

I have an **NSManagedObject** with `options` property of type `NSString`. but the response I receive from server for **this property** is in NSArray.  I want a custom mapper to convert this array to a a concatenated string.
if want to post this object to the server I need convert back this string to NSSArray.
How can I achieve that?

I don't want define an entity named `Options` and define a relationship between these objects.

```
options: 
{
red,
green,
blue,
}

||
\/

options = "red, green, blue";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider storing `options` as a transformable so that it is stored directly as an `NSArray`, and then have a transient property which is the string version of this, created and cached as required. Then you have access to the information in both formats and you can use each as required.